# What is this following filter circuit called? (For amplifiers)

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, audio, passive-filter, high-pass-filter

Noob here. I have a doubt on these passive low and high pass filters for amplifiers. If this is called high pass filter (which is doubled in series)[image: high pass filter],
then what is this filter circuit called?[image: another filter]
Here's the schematic of it (sorry if there are any mistakes, I just learnt how to draw them)
[image: Schematic]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way the capacitors are currently drawn is a bit confusing, and reflects their physical wiring rather than their actual configuration.

It is helpful to redraw the circuit slightly, so the two signal paths are more clearly visible.
The capacitor values are not given, but I will assume that they are all identical to start.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnr6fN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The top path has a lowpass characteristic, while the bottom path has a high-pass characteristic.

By simulating the circuit, we can see that *if the capacitors are identical* the filter has a notch-like behavior, blocking a narrow band of frequencies:

[image]

Note that the exact frequency of the notch will vary depending on the actual capacitor values. If the capacitor values are not all equal, then the filter has a more gradual stopband with less attenuation (shown here with C1 = 5 uF):

[image]

Also note that the simulation design itself encodes a few key assumptions: the input has very low source impedance, and the output has minimal loading (high input impedance)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and clear explaination. Those capacitors are identical with 2.2uf.